# how to use charts in HTML without plugin's

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to have charts in HTML without any jquery plugin ( flot,fusioncharts,chartjs etc.) or a bootstrap plugin.
any reference on how to do is also helpful..

Comment: You can make simple charts with CSS. Eg.: http://www.ssiddique.info/dynamic-chart-in-css.html

Comment: @phillip100 thanks for the info .. But CSS3 is not supported in IE8 right..coz the application needs suport in IE8 too..

Comment: You should mention this in the question

Comment: what kind of data you want to display in a chart?

Comment: its a burndown chart which shows the change in attendence every month..

Answer (score 0):

Drawing a chart without plugin and just with html code, you can find here..

http://javainfinite.com/html/how-to-draw-chart-in-html/